# Why the autorun service can't execute at poweroff?

Tags: bash, systemd

```
cat /lib/systemd/system/test_shutdown.service       
[Unit]        
Description=hello world        
Before=poweroff.target shutdown.target reboot.target   
[Service]        
Type=oneshot        
ExecStart=/bin/bash   /home/test_shutdown.sh         
[Install]        
WantedBy=poweroff.target  shutdown.target reboot.target      

cat  /home/test_shutdown.sh   
echo "haha" > /home/test_sys/shutdown.txt        

ls  -al  /home/test_shutdown.sh        
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 42 Mar 31 19:08 /home/test_shutdown.sh        

ls  -al  /home/test_sys        
drwxrwxrwx  2 root root 4096 Mar 31 19:12         
drwxr-xr-x 14 root root 4096 Mar 31 19:08 

systemctl  enable  test_shutdown.service
```

No /home/test_sys/shutdown.txt after rebooting,why my service can't be executed?

I have rewrite the /lib/systemd/system/test_shutdown.service  as following.

```
[Unit]    
Description=hello world   
DefaultDependencies=no   
Before=reboot.target poweroff.target shutdown.target    
[Service]    
ExecStart=echo "haha" >  /home/test_sys/test.txt   
Type=oneshot   
[Install]     
WantedBy=reboot.target  poweroff.target shutdown.target    

systemctl status test_shutdown.service
test_shutdown.service - hello world
Loaded: error (Reason: Invalid argument)
Active: inactive (dead)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

journalctl |grep test_shutdown.service
Apr 01 15:05:54 hwy systemd[1]: Configuration file /lib/systemd/system/test_shutdown.service is marked executable. Please remove executable permission bits. Proceeding anyway.

chmod 644   /lib/systemd/system/test_shutdown.service

Answer (score 1):

In your second service file, it should be

```
ExecStart=/bin/echo "haha" > /home/test_sys/test.txt
```

systemd need an absolute path.

You haven't gave the `systemctl status` of your first code. It could be write permission issue, or may be your shell interpreter is not `/bin/bash`. Might better use shebang `#!/bin/sh` in the shell script.

Answer (score 0):

```
[Unit]
Description=hello world
DefaultDependencies=no
Before=shutdown.target reboot.target halt.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/bin/bash /home/test_shutdown.sh
Type=oneshot
```

Comment: systemctl status test_shutdown.service
● test_shutdown.service - hello world
   Loaded: error (Reason: Invalid argument)
   Active: inactive (dead)